# Change user role based on total items purchased in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, user-roles

In Woocommerce I am trying to combine these two functions:

The [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621959/get-user-total-purchased-items-count-in-woocmmmerce/51626309#51626309) gets the total amount of ordered items by a user (all time)

```
function get_user_total_purchased_items( $user_id = 0 ){
    global $wpdb;

    $customer_id = $user_id === 0 ? get_current_user_id() : (int) $user_id;

    return (int) $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT SUM(woim.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON woi.order_id = p.ID
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON woi.order_id = pm.post_id
        WHERE woi.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status IN ('wc-completed')
        AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value LIKE '$customer_id'
        AND woim.meta_key LIKE '_qty'
    " );
}
```

And the second one changes user role if user orders a certain item.

```
function change_role_on_purchase( $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $product_variation_id = $item['variation_id'];

        if ( $order->user_id > 0 && $product_id == '416' ) {
            update_user_meta( $order->user_id, 'paying_customer', 1 );
            $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );

            // Remove role
            $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' ); 

            // Add role
            $user->add_role( 'premium' );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'change_role_on_purchase' );
```

What I am trying to accomplish is that if a user has ordered 50-99 items totally his user role is to be changed from standard_user to bronze_user and if he has ordered 100-199 his user role bronze_user -> silver_user and if total items exceed 200 hus user role silver_user -> gold_user.

The first function works well and comes from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51621959/get-user-total-purchased-items-count-in-woocmmmerce/51626309#51626309).

Now just trying to figure out how to implement it into the second function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3 your code is a bit outdated and need some changes. The following should change the user role conditionally based on number of purchased items *(untested)*:

```
function get_user_total_purchased_items( $user_id = 0 ){
    global $wpdb;

    $customer_id = $user_id === 0 ? get_current_user_id() : (int) $user_id;

    return (int) $wpdb->get_var( "
        SELECT SUM(woim.meta_value)
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS woi
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p ON woi.order_id = p.ID
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON woi.order_id = pm.post_id
        WHERE woi.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
        AND p.post_status IN ('wc-completed')
        AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user'
        AND pm.meta_value LIKE '$customer_id'
        AND woim.meta_key LIKE '_qty'
    " );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'change_role_on_purchase', 20, 2 );
function change_role_on_purchase( $order_id, $order ) {

    $user_id   = $order->get_customer_id();
    $user      = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $purchases = get_user_total_purchased_items( $user_id );

    if( $purchases >= 50 &&  $purchases < 100 && ! in_array( 'bronze_user', $user->roles ) ) {
        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'bronze_user' );
    }
    elseif( $purchases >= 100 &&  $purchases < 200 && ! in_array( 'silver_user', $user->roles ) ) {
        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'bronze_user' );

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'silver_user' );
    }
    elseif( $purchases >= 200 && ! in_array( 'gold_user', $user->roles ) ) {
        // Remove role
        $user->remove_role( 'silver_user' );

        // Add role
        $user->add_role( 'gold_user' );
    }

    if ( $user_id > 0 && $product_id == '416' ) {
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
            if ( $order->user_id > 0 && $item->get_product_id() == '416' ) {
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'paying_customer', 1 );

                // Remove role
                $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

                // Add role
                $user->add_role( 'premium' );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). I hope it will work, as I can't test it.

---

For reference regarding orders in Woocommerce 3:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: Thanks for replying. It didnt work unfortunately. Tried changing woocommerce_order_status_processing to woocommerce_order_status_completed on the second function as the first function counts completed orders - it may take into account the current order. Anyway not sure what could be wrong, nothing really happens and no errors :/

Comment: @Viktor I am going to check that later, as to test the code I need to set some user roles in a test server… But the way in my code (the philosophy) is the good one. I will notify you here.

Comment: Hello, have you been able to test it or found anything yet? Thanks

Comment: Got help and found a solution, $customer_id in second function is not defined. Changed to $user_id and it worked!